# Pairing after Blindfolding - Expected Value

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, expected-value

6 girls and 9 boys are blindfolded and are made to enter a room. All the 15 people are blindfolded and get shuffled up randomly such that all orderings are equally likely. The girls and boys come out of the room. How many boys, on average, are immediately followed by a girl?

My take: I was thinking of making pairs and then counting the possible cases,  by pair I mean a pair of Boy and Girl which will ensure that a boy is being followed by a girl. The number of pairs will vary from 0 to 6. But I feel this is not the right way to approach this question. Am I missing out on some concepts which I might not be familiar will to solve this question?

Comment: Linearity of expectation sounds like it could be very useful here.  Have you heard of it?  Let one of our boys be named Adam.  What is the probability that Adam is the last child out of the room?  Given that Adam is not the last child out of the room, what is the probability that a girl was the person immediately behind Adam?  (*Note that all of the other children are equally likely to be the child immediately behind Adam*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a particular boy, named $i$ ($i=1,\ldots, 9$).
The probability that he is followed directly by a girl is $\tfrac{14}{15}\cdot\tfrac{6}{14}$ (he must not be in the last place + symmetry of the rest of the people.). Let $X_i=1$ if boy $i$ is followed by a girl ($0$ otherwise) and $X$ the total number of boys that are followed by a girl.
Since $X=\sum\limits_{i=1}^9 X_i$ we get $$E(X)=E(\sum\limits_{i=1}^9 X_i)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^9 E(X_i)= \sum\limits_{i=1}^9 \tfrac{14}{15}\cdot\tfrac{6}{14}=3.6$$

Comment: So, the term 6/14 is the probability that the boy will take a position just before a girl, right?

Comment: Yes. Easier for me to think as a girl behind this boy.